# MySQL to HTML table in PHP not displaying all MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
exit;
}
else{



$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        $data[] = $row;
}

$columns = array_keys(reset($data));

echo '<table>';
echo '<table border="3">';
echo '<tr>';

                foreach($columns as $column)
                {
                echo "<th>$column</th>";
                }
echo '</tr>';

foreach($data as $row);
{
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($columns as $column)
        {
             echo '<td>'.$row[$column].'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
}
```

I'm not an expert (obviously) with either MySQL or PHP, and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. It's only displaying the final row in the MySQL table. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Well you're echoing `<table>` twice.  Are you sure there's more than one row in the DB?  what does your query look like?

Comment: My query looks like this; mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");

Comment: `print_r($data)` before `$columns = array_keys(reset($data));` and see what the $data array looks like.

Comment: 'people' is just the table that I'm grabbing the info from. also, where did I echo table twice?

Comment: @user2943358 You have `echo <table>` followed by `echo <table border=3>`

Comment: printing displays the correct contents

Comment: oh, I thought <table border = "x"> was a separate command. thanks

Comment: @ExplosionPills nah, those are fine. they're just for displaying the titles/headers for each column

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fill your row array like this:

```
$data = array();
$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $data[$index] = $row;
    $index++;
}
```

Comment: His way of filling the array works just as well, and it doesn't use an index variable.

Comment: `$array[] = $value;` is short for `array_push($array, $value);` :)